# Use HTTP in InnoSetup

Tags: http, inno-setup

I want to do some HTTP request during the installation of a software with InnoSetup.
Can I use the class `TStream` to open an URL as if it was a file or must I use the `Exec` function with curl.exe being attached in the installer, or is there an easier way ?

Comment: Is the use of `isxdl.dll` helpful for you?

Comment: Yup indeed, just accepted your answer, thanks a lot ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have a look at [ISTool](http://sourceforge.net/projects/istool/) and the distributed `isxdl.dll`. Also [Inno Setup](http://www.jrsoftware.org/) comes with the script `setup.iss` in the `examples` folder which utilizes the isxdl.dll for downloading additional setup files.